# Regex to mask GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN in github Authentication URL

Tags: javascript, regex

I get the error JSON response with Github access Token in the URL and displayed as shown below. I want to find and mask it like "xxxx". Anybody please help on this

Example :
https://abcdefghijkl:x-oauth-basic@github.com/api/reponame

i want generic regex to mask "abcdefghijkl" as "xxx" and finally get https://xxx:x-oauth-basic@github.com/api/reponame

Answer (score 2):

Here is the regex that you need :

```js
/(https:\/\/)\w+(:x-oauth-basic@github.com\/api\/[\w-]+)/
```

**E.g**:

```js
var re = /(https:\/\/)\w+(:x-oauth-basic@github.com\/api\/[\w-]+)/;  
var str = 'https://abcdefghijkl:x-oauth-basic@github.com/api/reponame';

str.replace(re, '$1xxxxxx$2');
// outputs : "https://xxxxx:x-oauth-basic@github.com/api/reponame"
```

check it live : [here](https://regex101.com/r/lM8dK5/1)